# val() does not grab the current input value

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to grab the value of an input field, but it won't grab it when it's updated. I'm trying to create an ajax log in form. Here's the code

```
<form method="post" id="contactform">
    <label for="name">Username</label>
    <input type="text"  id="un" placeholder="Username"  />

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password"  id="pw" placeholder="Password"  />

    <br/>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" id="submit" onclick="logUserIn(); return false;">Log In</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function logUserIn()
    {
        var un = $("#un").val();
        var pw = $("#pw").val();

        alert(un);
    }
    </script>
```

If I type something in the input field and click the submit button it won't update for me.

If I were to change the input value field manually like this

```
<input type="text"  id="un" placeholder="Username" value="test" />
```

Then I get alerted "test".

Comment: I copy/pasted it, and it works for me.

Comment: Works fine. Make sure you are referencing the jQuery library in the head of the document. Try using jQuery instead of $ if there is a possibility of a conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you write your JavaScript unobtrusively, i.e. keep everything JavaScript in a script tag and leave the markup separate. See [Unobtrusive JavaScript - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

HTML:

```
    <form method="post" id="contactform">
      <label for="name">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="un" placeholder="Username" />
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="pw" placeholder="Password"
      />
      <br/>
      <button id="btnLogin" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" id="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $('#btnLogin').click(logUserIn);
});

function logUserIn() {
  var un = $("#un").val();
  var pw = $("#pw").val();

  alert(un);

  return false;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Gadm/4/)

Comment: `$('#btnLogin').click(logUserIn);` needs to be inside the `$(document).ready` function.

Comment: This ends up refreshing the page and then I get an alert box after the refresh

Comment: Wrapped the click event binding inside doc.ready as pointed out by @wired_in - see updated code.

Comment: Well the alert doesn't up anymore, but it's still refreshing.

Comment: Check your console for errors. Follow the link to the live demo to see it working

Comment: Alright, well this works fine. Thank you :) I was missing that.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of val() on the jquery site states "Get the current value of the **first** element in the set of matched elements".  I am not sure what "element" refers to but stepping through my Javascript in debug mode I could see that the jquery object (that is returned by $('#field_id') held the original value in the first array element but after the input text was changed, the updated value was held in a second array element.  Using last() worked for me, e.g. $('#field_id').last().val();

Answer (score 2):

Add empty value attribute to the input tags, i hope this might work for you. Eg:

```
<input type="text"  id="un" placeholder="Username" value="" />
<input type="password"  id="pw" placeholder="Password" value="" />
```